# "Unable to restore from current backup" when restoring WhatsApp chat from Google Drive

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, restore, google-drive

I have changed my phone. I had backed up my WhatsApp data on Google Drive. Google Drive shows the chat has been backed up there.

On the new phone, I reinstalled WhatsApp with the same phone number and opted to restore data. It only restores media files but no chat messages. Restoring messages stops at 24% and shows error "Unable to restore from current backup".

How can I restore my chat?

Answer (score -1):

Open Whatsapp. If you have the chat backup, it will display a message "Backup found. Do you want to restore?" If not, then Go to Settings->Chats->Chat Backup. You will find the Google Drive option. Click on it and you are good to go.

Make sure you got your email account linked to the phone.

Comment: OP said they already tried to restore and it stopped halfway through. BTW the same happened to me as well.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Any solution found?

Comment: @Chanikya that comment was made 7 years ago. :) I don't remember what the issue was. Anyways, you can usually download the backup manually from Google Drive with some open source tools and then decrypt the database to see if the file is damaged.